# C# .NET Core Set a default for custom method attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This is about a .NET Core MVC API Application.

I have defined a custom attribute which checks the role for a user. I now have to add this as an attribute to all my methods to make sure a token has the right claims.

How would I set a default for this so it is not neccessary to add this attribute to all methods? If I forget to add it, it should assume highest role, so users with lower permission will get an access denied.

So for example:

```
[Role(UserRole.ADMIN)]
public getAllUsers()  {} // As ADMIN is the highest role only admins can access

[Role(UserRole.CLIENT)]
public getMyData() { } // As CLIENT is the lowest role, everyone can access

public getStatistics() { } // As I forgot to set the attribute, only admins should be able to access
```

#### Update:

As requested, my attribute class. It is relatively simple I think, but for checking the permisions, it does the job:

```
    public class RoleAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public RoleAttribute(UserRole role) : base(typeof(RoleFilter)) { 
            Arguments = new object[] { role };
        }
    }

    public class RoleFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        readonly UserRole role;

        public RoleFilter(UserRole role)
        {
            this.role = role;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {

            var hasRole = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" && (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRole), x.Value) <= (int)role);
            if (!hasRole)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Update 2

Using a constructor does not help.

With this:

```
public RoleAttribute(UserRole role = UserRole.ADMIN) : base(typeof(RoleFilter)) {
```

I still have to add at least:

```
[Role()]
public getStatistics() { }
```

But I want to accomplish (without any attribute):

```
public getStatistics() { }
```

Comment: Is your attribute a filter? if not maybe change your attribute to be able to apply on classes?

Comment: Yes, it inherits from TypeFilterAttribute/IAuthorizationFilter

Comment: Show us your attribute class please.

Comment: @PaulSinnema , see update

Comment: You could add a default value to the constructor `public RoleAttribute(UserRole role = UserRole.ADMIN) : base(typeof(RoleFilter))`

Comment: Not shure if the compiler allows that. Might complain about it not being a constant. How is UsereRole.ADMIN declared?

Comment: It is an enum. It is passed to the API via a json web token.

Adding a default to the constructor does not solve my problem. Then I still have to add the attribute, just without parameter.

Comment: I think it is unavoidable to add attributes to your class members. Have you considered adding an attribute to your class instead?

Comment: Adding the attribute to the class is a good option, but then I have to design it so that all the methods of that class have the same permission as it cannot be overruled. Guess I have to rethink this in general. Thank you all for your comments so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wants to accomplish the same:

This problem is solved by creating a unit test which runs after every build. It does not accomplish the possibility of the absence of an attribute but enforces its existence.

The test comes down to:

- Retrieving all controllers
- Iterate over the controllers and check if they include the RoleAttribute
- If not, retrieve all methods of the controller
- Check if the method includes the RoleAttribute OR AllowAnonymousAttribute

So:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckExistenceOfRoleAttributeDecorator()
{
    var types = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetTypes();
    var controllers = types.Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ControllerBase)) && !t.IsAbstract);
    foreach (var controller in controllers)
    {
        if (!controller.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RoleAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            var actions = controller.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (var action in actions)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(action.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RoleAttribute), true).Any() || action.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true).Any(), $"Attribute Role and AllowAnonymous not found on {controller.Name}.{action.Name}. Either one of those should be present.");
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            // This assert is always true because of the condition above, but added for readability of the logic.
            Assert.IsTrue(controller.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RoleAttribute), true).Any(), $"Attribute Role not found on {controller.FullName}");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is useful

Comment: The idea comes from: https://thomasardal.com/unit-testing-attribute-decorations/